# Set Column on Different Rows using RecyclerView Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, grid, gridlayoutmanager

Aoa i want to get Recyclerview show like this [image: I want output of RecyclerView view items like this]:

I used below GridLayoutManager code But i get output like this

```
   GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    manager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            return (position % 3) > 0 ? 1 : 2;
        }
    });
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    UserAdapter userAdapter = new UserAdapter(this,userModelList);
    rvItem.setLayoutManager(manager);
    rvItem.setAdapter(userAdapter);
```

[image: This is output i am getting]

Please guide me either this is possible? If yes then How?

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution might be doing the following :
Since what you are doing is sending the position that ranges from i=0 to n and you use  modulo of 3 . Hence if i=0  and i>0 is false that is why the first line is  1 and the second line is i=1 and i>0 that is why you get 2 ...

```
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return (position % 3) > 0 ? 2 : 1;
    }
```

How about switching the ternary condition and trying to maybe use modulo of 2 instead 3 ? Or maybe switch the 2 and 1 ?? It seems that you are on the right path a little experimentation will do the trick :) Best of luck !!!